# linux source installation

Tags: linux

If I've installed a software with ./configure --enable=abc make && make install

in future i need to install option xyz so will i've to use ./configure --enable=xyz or

./configure --enable=abc --enable=xyz ??

What if i don't use "./configure --enable=abc --enable=xyz" in future just use ./configure --enable=xyz would this affect on my previous configuration???

If i've forgotten that previously which options i enabled, in that case if only i enable the new option would that effect on the options which were enabled last time i compile and this time i missed them???

Is there not anyway to append instead of overwrite??

Comment: In addition to @XCondE, you should note that this is about the configuration of how the source code is compiled, this doesn't change the configuration of the application itself once installed (although which options are available will depend on what it's been compiled with, of course)

Answer (score 2):

The latter:

```
./configure --enable=abc --enable=xyz
```

Depending on the software you may need to do a make clean before re-running ./configure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will. The software will re-compile according to ONLY the options you specify at compile time, and if you install it again it will overwrite it with only the new configuration. Any features you forgot to compile the second time will no longer be usable.